# Issue with two canvas in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabric js. And I am showing two canvases with javascript show/hide property. The problem is that the element selection does not work on the second canvas. And in the first canvas the selection is not in proper position, the **move cursor** is in just below the selection.

```
<?php $url=base_url().'uploads/'.$info->image;
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url); ?>

<div class="col-md-8" id="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="<?php echo $width?>" height="<?php echo $height?>"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var img = '<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/<?php echo $info->image;?>';
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    </script>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" id="canvas-holder2">
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="<?php echo $width?>" height="<?php echo $height?>"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');
        var img2 = '<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/<?php echo $info->image;?>';
        canvas2.setBackgroundImage(img2, canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));
    </script>
</div>
```

Is there any solution of it ? ? ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try to reset the coordinates and call calcOffset()

```
        var updateCoords = function()
        {
            var objects = canvas.getObjects();
            for (var i in objects) {
                objects[i].setCoords();
            }
            canvas.calcOffset()
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
```